# Docker Compose connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.4:3306

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, sequelize.js

When I build the container of the project with this command:

```
sudo docker build -t PROJECT_NAME .
```

And then I download the mysql's image through this Docker-Compose config:

```
  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8999:3306"
    networks:
      - webnet
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: slack
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
```

And then, the project will connect with MySQL through the [Sequelize ORM](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/)

I have this error:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.4:3306
```

[image]

How can I resolve this?

The Sequelize config is this:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.TEST_DB || 'slack', 'root', 'admin', {
  host: process.env.DB_HOST || 'localhost',
  operatorsAliases: Sequelize.Op,
  dialect: 'mysql',
  define: {
    underscored: true
  }
});
```

The config of the web is this:

```
web:
    image: slack-clone-server
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - webnet
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db
      REDIS_HOST: redis
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:3306", "--", "npm", "run", "prod"]
```

The script called "wait for it" is [this](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/blob/master/wait-for-it.sh).

If someone needs the complete code, here you go:

[Sequelize config](https://github.com/MontoyaAndres/slack-clone/blob/master/server/src/models/index.js)

[Docker Compose config](https://github.com/MontoyaAndres/slack-clone/blob/master/server/docker-compose.yml)

[Dockerfile config](https://github.com/MontoyaAndres/slack-clone/blob/master/server/Dockerfile)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wait-for-it.sh` by default waits for [15 seconds](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/blob/master/wait-for-it.sh#L139) and returns, even if the target isn't ready yet.  You see that in your output too.  But the database isn't ready yet.  Make `wait-for-it.sh` [wait longer](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/blob/master/wait-for-it.sh#L110), maybe with `-t 90` to wait for 90 seconds or `-t 0` to make it wait forever.

(In my experience the Docker database containers routinely take 30-60 seconds to start up, especially the first time.)

Answer (score 2):

David already said that the db is not ready at this moment. You can use **depends_on** in your docker-compose file as well. This will start and initialize the db first and then start the "web" container.

```
services:
  web:
    ...
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    ...
```

Comment: Interesting! Thanks!

Comment: `depends_on:` is almost a no-op.  For a while it supported Docker health checks but I believe this isn’t part of the current schema version.  If you `docker-compose up web` it will also start `db`, but it won’t wait for it to actually become available; it will just start one and then immediately start the next.

Answer (score 0):

```
db:
    container_name: mysqldb //or whatever you want <<Add This
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8999:3306"
    networks:
      - webnet
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: slack
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
```

And Then assign the value of `process.env.DB_HOST` to **Mysql Container name**

Like: `process.env.DB_HOST=mysqldb`

Answer (score 0):

Assign the value of process.env.DB_HOST to Mysql Container name

Like: process.env.DB_HOST=mysqldb