# Docker Docs' Get Started Guide: Got mysql:3306 Timeout Using Docker Compose

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose

I've just started learning docker through the official Docker docs. I got an error that I can't solve at Part 8: Use Docker Compose (https://docs.docker.com/get-started/08_using_compose/). The error is as follows.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
    app:
        image: node:18-alpine
        command: sh -c "yarn install && yarn run dev"
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
        working_dir: /app
        volumes:
            - ./:/app
        environment:
            MYSQL_HOST: mysql
            MYSQL_USER: root
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
            MYSQL_DB: todos

    mysql:
        image: mysql:8.0
        volumes:
            - todo-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
            MYSQL_DATABASE: todos

volumes:
    todo-mysql-data:
```

`docker compose logs -f`

```
app-mysql-1  | 2023-05-08 08:54:16+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.33-1.el8 started.
app-mysql-1  | 2023-05-08 08:54:17+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
app-app-1    | yarn install v1.22.19
app-mysql-1  | 2023-05-08 08:54:17+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.33-1.el8 started.
app-mysql-1  | 2023-05-08 08:54:18+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
app-mysql-1  | 2023-05-08T08:54:18.067167Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
app-mysql-1  | 2023-05-08T08:54:18.069607Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33) initializing of server in progress as process 80
app-mysql-1  | 2023-05-08T08:54:18.131879Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
app-app-1    | [1/4] Resolving packages...
app-app-1    | success Already up-to-date.
app-app-1    | Done in 1.46s.
app-app-1    | yarn run v1.22.19
app-app-1    | $ nodemon src/index.js
app-app-1    | [nodemon] 2.0.20
app-app-1    | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
app-app-1    | [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
app-app-1    | [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
app-app-1    | [nodemon] starting `node src/index.js`
app-mysql-1  | 2023-05-08T08:54:42.445343Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
app-app-1    | Waiting for mysql:3306............
app-app-1    | Timeout
app-app-1    | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.2:3306
app-app-1    |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
app-app-1    |   errno: -111,
app-app-1    |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
app-app-1    |   syscall: 'connect',
app-app-1    |   address: '172.18.0.2',
app-app-1    |   port: 3306,
app-app-1    |   fatal: true
app-app-1    | }
app-app-1    | [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I've let the logs run for a while after the nodemon crashed line and the db seems to start after about 4 mins, since more logs containing "temporary server started" appeared. At this point, I could connect to the db successfully as well, tested through VSCode Database testing extension. This made me think the issue was the app trying to run before db is fully initialized so I looked up the internet and tried many solutions for that such as `wait-for-it.sh`, `restarts: always`, `healthcheck` and `depends_on`. But the error kept happening. More weird is that, my friend who tried the same thing by following the docs without any extra solution on his machine could run everything fine. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `depends_on` like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53592826

Thanks [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9162553/martin)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).